# Using multiple JedisPools

Tags: redis, jedis

Initially when I used 1 JedisPool to communicate with a Redis server (single instance of redis running on the server) I saw that my 200K queries took 15 sec to complete. For each query I do following:

```
Jedis jedis = pool.getResource();
Pipeline p = jedis.pipelined();
p.multi();
for (String ViewId : ViewIds) { 
    for (Article aR : view.getEntriesList()) {
        p.rpush(ViewId, <article-in-json>);
    }
    p.ltrim(ViewId, -10, -1);
} 
p.exec();
p.sync();
pool.returnResource(jedis);
```

JedisPool created using:

```
JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(), getHostName(), getPort(), 0, "foobared");
```

However when I used 8 JedisPools to the same server (same redis instance) and used them in a round robin way I saw that 200K queries were processed in around 8-10 secs (earlier with 1 JedisPool it took 15 sec) => considerable improvement.

What is the reason for this? and what is the optimal number of JedisPools that we should use?

Comment: This seems weird as using many JedisPool shouldn't mean performance gain in any way. It is possible that the pool get exhausted sometime in the middle of the process and there are waits for free resources. Maybe if you make sure you have enough free resources in the pool, with only one pool you could achieve those 8-10 seconds